# Is there any way to make Visual Studio C++ error output useful?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I find VS19 output quite useless when working on C++ project. Consider running the example code on freshly installed VS19:

```
#include <iostream>  

using namespace std;
class My
{
    public:
    void f() noexcept
    {
        throw exception{"A problem sir!"};
    }
};

int main() 
{
    try 
    {
        My m;
        m.f();
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "exception caught! " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I would like to receive is: "Function throws an exception while marked as noexcept", and the cursor set on the problematic line. What I get is a new window with some general text, none of which mentions the problem, or where the problem is.

Comment: _"a new window with some general text"_ What text? In what way is it "general"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to resolve your puzzle in your question:

> What I get is a new window with some general text, none of which
>   mentions the problem, or where the problem is.
>
> I find 90% of output useless for me.

I think what you mean is the [Output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window?view=vs-2019), it is always used to display output about build process.

Also, You can also program your own applications to write diagnostic messages at run time to an Output pane. To do this, use members of the [Debug class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug) or [Trace class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace) in the [System.Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics) namespace of the .NET Framework Class Library.

For those large solution or large project, which has plenty of resource files. The build sometimes fail with unknown error. The output window is necessary for trouble-shooting.

If you think most of its info is useless,like **P.PICARD** suggests: Go Tools=>Projects and Solutions=>Build and Run to set its **build output verbosity**(!Not build log file verbosity) I suggest you change it to **Minimal**.

If you have a failed build and want to watch the details of the whole build process. Change it to **Detailed** and rebuild the project or solution.

> What I would like to receive is: "Function throws an exception while
>   marked as noexcept", and the cursor set on the problematic line.

Have you checked the [Error List window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2019)? If it disappeared,choose View > Error List, or press Ctrl++E.

Add two lines to your code sample:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    int b;
...
}
```

Navigate to the Error List window(I suggest you set it as **Build and Intellisense**):
[image]

I think it's what you want. And error list window also indicates the Variable which is not initialized or not referenced for improving your coding.

Also, you can see their line numbers. And Double-click the error message, the cursor will navigate to that line.

For C++ program, the warning level is from w0 to w4, you can set it w4 to get the high warning level.(By default it should be w3)

Right-click project=>properties=>Configuration Properties=>C/C++=>Warning Level to set it. (Have been described by **Blastfurance**, thanks to him!)

Change it to w0, nothing shows. Change it to w3, and it will show warnings about `My::f` and `b` but not `a`.(Actually I don't think you make changes to that, because w3 is by default) Change it to w4 then get the high warning level and all associated warnings display.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I transfered from another IDE where problems were showed in my face in a user friendly way :) Dissapering Error List Window got me puzzled. Crucial information window, which I have to turn on through a menu to find where the problem is? But who am I to judge, at least there is a way :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to know it helps. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 6):

What compiler warning level have you specified? If I use the `/W0` option there is no diagnostic but with any other value, `/W1` through `/W4`, the compiler outputs the following lines:

```
1>filename.cpp(9,1): warning C4297:  'My::f': function assumed not to throw an exception but does
1>filename.cpp(9,1): message :  __declspec(nothrow), throw(), noexcept(true), or noexcept was specified on the function
```

Note: the diagnostic messages include the line and column numbers. If you double-click the error message it moves the cursor to the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

Your verbosity parameter of MSBuild is may be too high. Go to menu: Tools -> Options. Then on the left pane select: Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. 
There you can select the appropriate verbosity of MSBuild (from Quiet to Diagnostic)

Comment: I have OP's issue in one c++ project  in a solution1, I don't have it in other project from another solution2, yet both solution have the same paramets in "tools --> solutions --> project and solutions --> Build And Run".